# Are lockdowns good or bad? What is the scientific consensus, if any?

Tags: covid-19, virus, epidemiology

I thought doctors support lockdown measures and populist politicians oppose them, but then this ["Barrington Declaration"](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-54442386) cropped up and I don't know what to think now. Are lockdowns good or bad, after all? What is the scientific consensus, if any? Do mental health issues and other drawbacks really outweigh the risks of contracting and transmitting Covid-19?

Comment: you should know that many signatories of that document are made up names, and there's certainly no way to know how many are actually doctors. You might get more insight from this closed Skeptics question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48644/does-the-great-barrington-declaration-hold-any-water

Comment: Also, as written, your question can't be answered. Acetaminophen: good or bad? It fixes headaches and other pains, so doctors sometimes tell you to take it. But if you take as little as 6 times the dose on the box, and keep your liver busy with alcohol, you will die. Dying is bad, right? So what do doctors think of acetaminophen? It depends. Same with lockdowns. They have benefits and downsides. Listing all the downsides is not an argument.

Comment: Voted to close because answers likely to be opinion-based.

Comment: Regardless of lockdown, mental health issues is *also* a serious matter. Someone can become crazy and non-functional just by getting paranoid from the news.